# capture JNIENV* inside C++ lambda expression error

Tags: java, c++, lambda, java-native-interface

I have in my Main.cpp file a JNI call like this:

```
JNIEXPORT jstring   JNICALL
    Java_packagename_MainActivity_GenerateAlphabet(JNIEnv *env, jobject thiz)
        {
            generateAlphabet([](string letters, string numbers) {
                        return (env)->NewStringUTF("test");

            });
        }
```

but this code gives me the error:

**jni/Main.cpp: In lambda function:**

**jni/Main.cpp:86:33: error: 'env' is not captured**

I really need to use env in the lambda function, can anyone help me please.

**EDIT:**

The accepted answer resolves the problem, but please keep in mind that you cannot return a value inside a lambda expression.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can put `env` in the capture list using `[env]`.

**But**, this is a **very** bad idea. The captured `env` is only valid for a particular thread. If your lambda is ever called on a different thread then the result will not be defined.

You *could* capture the `JavaVM*` pointer in your lambda (which you can get from the passed `env`), and use `AttachCurrentThread` to retrieve an appropriate `env` within the lambda.

Comment: You can't say it's a bad idea unless you know what `generateAlphabet` does. (Most likely, it doesn't touch threading)

Comment: No. No. No. **Never** store the env pointer passed to the function. Unless you like 3am debugging sessions on production servers using little more than pdb files.

Comment: Is storing it in a local variable unacceptable too?

Comment: No, a normal local variable. `void function_name(JNIEnv *env) {JNIEnv *env2 = env;}`. Because you just said to never ever ever ever ever ever store it anywhere full stop. And a lambda capture, if the lambda is only called within method being invoked here, is as harmful as a local variable.

Comment: Would you create a thread-local variable in order to use `env` in a comparator for `std::sort`, for example? Or would you just capture it?

Comment: You can use the passed env in any way you fancy so long as you stay within the thread and the stackframe that the java runtime gives you on calling Java_packagename_MainActivity_GenerateAlphabet. Many helper classes (string guards, array guards) exploit this. I feel more involved discussion is out of scope of this question.

Answer (score 0):

In C++, you need to specify which variables are accessible inside your lambda exprsesion (aka *captured*).

The `[]` at the start is an empty capture list. Just add `env` inside it to capture `env` (by value):

```
[env](string letters, string numbers) {
    return (env)->NewStringUTF("test");
});
```